# How to invert colors in LESS

Tags: colors, less

Is there a particular color operation I'm not seeing where you can invert colors? I'm seeing lots of color methods but could not see a way to do this.

reference:

http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are multiple interpretation of inverting color.

- You want a color with the opposite hue:

  `spin(@color, 180)`
- You want a color that the sum with current one is white:

  `#fff - @color`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no `invert()` function in Less.

I think Less function `spin()` can be very helpful as [xiaoyi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676802/4316314) highlights. Use it on "colorful" colors like red or blue (`spin(red, 180)`) and we get the inverted color but we don't really get the same result on very dark or light colors since there's not much hue to rotate. For instance `spin(#000011, 180)` compiles into color #111100, which is also very dark.

I wanted to set the color of paragraphs to `black` if the background is light and set it to `white` if the background is dark. Here's how I do it with `if()`, `boolean()` and `luma()`:

```
@bkg-color: #001;
@is-bg-dark: boolean(luma(@bkg-color) > 50%);

.container {
  background-color: @bkg-color;
}

p {
  color: if(@is-bg-dark, black, white);
}
```

[Read more about Less functions](http://lesscss.org/functions/#logical-functions-boolean) such as boolean().

Answer (score -6):

I don't think there is a specific function to invert colors, but what you could do is set your colors as variables. e.g.:

```
@color1: #666;
@color2: #fff;

body {
background-color: @color1;
color: @color2;
}

h1 {
color: @color2;
}
```

Then, simply make an alternate stylesheet with the inverted colors set to the variables used in the primary stylesheet. As long as you use the variables throughout the css, those color will be inverted.

Comment: I +1 you but I would like a way to do this within the LESS environment if possible.