# Invert all colors with LESS

Tags: php, css, colors, less

I have a stylesheet I am happy with and I compile it using the following code. Works great.

```
function css($inputFile, $outputFile)
{
    $cacheFile = $inputFile.".cache";

    $cache = file_exists($cacheFile)
        ? unserialize(file_get_contents($cacheFile))
        : $inputFile;

    $less = new lessc;
    $less->setFormatter("compressed");
    $newCache = $less->cachedCompile($cache);

    if ( ! file_exists($outputFile) || ! is_array($cache) || $newCache["updated"] > $cache["updated"])
    {
        file_put_contents($cacheFile, serialize($newCache));
        file_put_contents($outputFile, $newCache['compiled']);
    }
}
```

I there a simple way to produce a version of the stylesheet with absolutely all defined colors inverted? Can you do something fancy with the LESS compiler or something?

The reason I'm curious about this is because the site looks decent when I invert a screen shot of it, and it would be cool to have a cheap way to generate a light on dark version of the site which is currently dark on light.

Any clever ideas?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676501/how-to-invert-colors-in-less

Comment: You would have to know your color variables, and redefine them spinning the hue 180 degrees.

Comment: @helderdarocha Yeah, that seems pretty doable. The challenge is to do it automatically somehow. Preferably without editing the existing `less` files at all.

Comment: If all your colors are in variables, you can use `less.modifyVars()` to replace them. You can also generate the inverted colors using PHP, and just replace the variables with strings.

Comment: Only a few colors are in variables, the others are calculated based on those. Which works great when working with dark colors, but if I used light colors everything would be white basically :)

Comment: Yeah, you don't really want to invert the variables (that you calculate other colors from) but rather all the color property values before compiling the output CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply extend the `lessc` class and modify the compiler so that all colors get inverted.

We add a new class (for example `lessc_invert`) that extends class `lessc`, and now we just need to:

- define a simple function for inverting colors: `invert_color($c){ return abs($c - 255); }`
- and override the `protected function compileValue($value)` from `lessc`, where we:

  - coerce values of type `'raw_color'` to type `'color'`,
  - coerce values of type `'keyword'` to `'color'` (if it's found in the `$cssColors` array)
  - and then invert the `$r, $g, $b` components of the color using the `invert_color()` function.

Something like this:

```
class lessc_invert extends lessc {
  protected function invert_color($c){
    return abs($c - 255);
  }
  protected function compileValue($value) {
    switch ($value[0]) {
    case 'list':
      return implode($value[1], array_map(array($this, 'compileValue'), $value[2]));
    case 'raw_color':
      return $this->compileValue($this->coerceColor($value));
    case 'keyword':
      if (isset(self::$cssColors[$value[1]])) {
        return $this->compileValue($this->coerceColor($value));
      }
      return $value[1];
    case 'number':
      list(, $num, $unit) = $value;
      if ($this->numberPrecision !== null) {
        $num = round($num, $this->numberPrecision);
      }
      return $num . $unit;
        case 'string':
      list(, $delim, $content) = $value;
      foreach ($content as &$part) {
        if (is_array($part)) {
          $part = $this->compileValue($part);
        }
      }
      return $delim . implode($content) . $delim;
    case 'color':
      list(, $r, $g, $b) = $value;
      $r = $this->invert_color(round($r));
      $g = $this->invert_color(round($g));
      $b = $this->invert_color(round($b));
      if (count($value) == 5 && $value[4] != 1) {
        return 'rgba('.$r.','.$g.','.$b.','.$value[4].')';
      }
      $h = sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", $r, $g, $b);
      if (!empty($this->formatter->compressColors)) {
        if ($h[1] === $h[2] && $h[3] === $h[4] && $h[5] === $h[6]) {
          $h = '#' . $h[1] . $h[3] . $h[5];
        }
      }      
      return $h;
    case 'function':
      list(, $name, $args) = $value;
      return $name.'('.$this->compileValue($args).')';
    default:
      $this->throwError("unknown value type: $value[0]");
    }
  }
}
```

And now instead of instantiating `lessc` we can use our new class `lessc_invert`, like so:

```
$less = new lessc_invert;
$less->setFormatter("compressed");
$newCache = $less->cachedCompile($cache);
```

This should do the trick =)

---

**For example:**

```
echo $less->compile("a { color: blue; }");
```

now returns:

```
a{color:#ff0;}
```

Comment: That does look quite promising! Will try it out later today :)

Comment: That totally worked! Awesome. Any idea how to not invert shadows?

Comment: to do stuff specific to a property you need to include also the `compileProp()` method, here I made [**a gist** (*https://gist.github.com/mturjak/9684082*)](https://gist.github.com/mturjak/9684082) where I added a switch `$f` to the `invert_color()` method and changes this switch based on the property `$name` in `compileProp()` with `$this->f = preg_match('/shadow/',$name) ? 0 : 1;`, so the colors don't get inverted if the property is a shadow (box-shadow or text-shadow), but of course you can modify this to your needs.